# Progressbar with different colours for right and wrong

Tags: java, android

I want to set up a progressbar with different colours. When the answer is correct, that part of the the progressbar which changes should be green, when it is incorrect is should be red.

[Here is a bad paint example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35s7i.png)

From what I have seen looking around on the web, this is not doable with progressbars. How else could I achieve this or what would be a possible solution?

Comment: `this is not doable with progressbars` then don't use a progress bar. you can easily achieve this using textviews (or even just a View) with different background colors. if you need it to be dynamic, use a recyclerview

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.